# How to grep the data only for the first two combination and perform > operation

Tags: perl, shell, tcl

I have a file as shown below.

```
2.6G    kishan  /home/Srikishan
10G     kishan  /home/data/aa
150G    kishan  /home/Junk
300G    kishan  /home/junk2
```

I want a command which displays only the folders which are consuming more than 50G memory. Can someone help me how I can code it using shell or Perl or TCL.

Comment: Hint: If you work on Linux you also can just use the program `ncdu` if you just want to find the folder manualy and you don't need it in any automation.

Comment: What hppens when the folder only has 999M in it?

Answer (score 2):

As a Perl one-liner

```
perl -ne'/([\d.]+)G/ and $1 > 50 and print' myfile
```

**output**

```
150G    kishan  /home/Junk
300G    kishan  /home/junk2
```

This will also ignore lines that don't contain a field like `999G`

Answer (score 1):

And here's the Tcl contender. It looks at every line in the file whose name is in the `filename` variable and prints those lines that begin with a floating-point number larger than 50.

```
package require fileutil

fileutil::foreachLine line $filename {if {[scan $line %f] > 50} {puts $line}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk -F 'G' '$1>50' file
150G kishan /home/Junk
300G kishan /home/junk2
```